# addListenerForSingleEvent is getting triggered every time data is changed in firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently making a project in which i just want is to call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` only in `onCreate()` function and not everytime data is being changed in Firebase database

In this i just want to fetch data only once when it is created and code for that is as follows :

```
cancelRef.child(code).child("Member").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Fetch DATA
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: A listener you attach with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent ` will get triggered only once, when you first attach it. If you're seeing `onDataChange` being called multiple times, it is most likely because you're attaching this listener multiple times. The best way to troubleshoot this is by setting a breakpoint on `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and running the app in a debugger, to see when that triggers.

Comment: i dont think so that i have attached listener multiple times , should i attach whole code ?

Comment: I told you how to troubleshoot it. And your question should include the minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone of us can run to reproduce the problem. Taking a snippet out of your complete app is not enough. I've run code like yours hundreds of times, and never seen it call the `onDataChange` multiple times for a single call to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. If my previous tips don't help you solve the problem yourself, I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to isolate the problem.